# Are linked images automatically updated to StackExchange's imgur account?

Tags: support, images, imgur

Are linked images automatically updated to StackExchange's imgur account? I noticed many of the linked images within questions and answer are hosted at `i.stack.imgur.com`. If not, then how can I upload pics and screenshots to that account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from [August 2010](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/),  all images uploaded using the image uploader on the toolbar get saved to Stack Exchange's imgur account.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I never use the toolbar for anything so that went completely over my head.